# Reporting Services report

Tags: pdf, reporting-services, reporting, reportingservices-2005

I created a report in reporting services 2005 with a report page size of 14in x 8.5in. The report looks fine in the reports manager and also in the report viewer. The issue is when I export the report to PDF, the page size in Adobe states 14 x 8.5 in but when you hit the print button, it selects Letter size (8.5 x 11) instead of choosing Legal size (8.5 x 14).
If you then click on 'Choose Paper Source by PDF page size' or change the paper source to legal, the report prints out exactly the way I wanted it.

Does anyone have a solution to this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I remeber we had a similar problem a few months ago with Reporting Services 2008 (not 2005).

I think the solution was to "force" the values of Width and Heigth for the desired amount, regardless of the selected item in "Paper size" dropdown box (in Report Properties -> Page Setup)

In our case, we wanted to print in A4, so we set width = 21.59cm and height = 27,94cm, even if selected paper size remains as "Letter".

Comment: That's right, the report canvas size doesn't determine the page size, it's the page setup settings under report properties.

Comment: The page size under Reports -> Report properties -> Layout is set to 
Page Width: 14in, Page Height: 8.5in

I would have assumed that this should have done it but when I exported it out to pdf and did a print, it comes out 11 x 8.5 (scaled).

Answer (score 1):

Just i choosed the **Report Properties** -> **Page Setup** --> **Paper Size** is A4 , then it was get working fine for A4
- GAM SKJai (L&T ECC)

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem too, and I've never found a satisfactory solution. SSRS doesn't offer much control over print settings in export formats (like fit-to-one-page-across in Excel).

One work-around would be to roll your own interface, intercept the PDF file, and update the print settings before serving it up to the user. Could be a lot of work, and how would you know the intended page size? You could always parse the RDL file for the page size settings, and that would be a correct solution, but damn if that's not a lot of extra work.

EDIT: check the page size under page setup, as pv2008 suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Report Properties --> Interactive Size set it to whatever you want and it stays, even after closing and reopening the report. I exported pdf and it retains the size. You can check by right clicking on the pdf and go tot properties.